# Does Linux Kernel allows a process to consume 100% memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

If there is any process which need 100% of memory,for which no resource limitation has imposed. Does Linux Kernel allows it to consume 100% memory if needed?If not, how kernel will work in such scenario?

Comment: this is what swap space is for. compile `while(malloc(1));` and watch it go.

Comment: Okay.Will try it right now.

Comment: The linux kernel doesn't hand out physical memory, it works with *virtual-memory*, so you can have a process, many processes, demanding 100% of the memory. The days of handing out chunks of physical memory died with *real-mode* computing in the early '90's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any process?
if you don't manually put a limit there, any process can take 100% of your memory. when it runs out of memory the OOM Killer will go on a spree.
I read about these stuff in: [http://www.amazon.com/Linux-Kernel-Development-3rd-Edition/dp/0672329468](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468)

Comment: Not able to find related contents on the provided link.

Comment: dat, sir, is your problem. go play tetris.

Comment: Mr. the link you provided took me to amazon shopping portal. Do you wanted me to buy and read that book?

Comment: you could do that, you could look for an excerpt. google the title of the book and read the first link(pdf hosted at a university in france). but I legally can't give you a link to the content itself. it's simple commonsense. and you telling me there is no content on the provided link is not cool.

Comment: I know it's commonsense. Will do it my way.DW.